# BlocBuilder not rebuilding on floating action button click

Tags: android, flutter, setstate, bloc, do-not-use-typo-in-tag

Using Bloc pattern to show a list of data fetched from rest api.
Now I want to update the list on listview on button click.
When I click on button, it fetches the data but it does not update the listview
Here is the complete code.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:bloc_demo/homepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomePage.dart**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String pageNo = "1";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => UserBloc(UserRepository(),pageNo),
        ),
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('The BloC App')),
        body: blocBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            pageNo = "2";
            UserBloc(
              UserRepository(),pageNo,
            ).add(LoadUserEvent());
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget blocBody() {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => UserBloc(
        UserRepository(),pageNo,
      )..add(LoadUserEvent()),
      child: BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is UserLoadingState) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (state is UserLoadedState) {
            List<UserModel> userList = state.users;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: userList.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
                    child: Card(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              '${userList[index].firstName}  ${userList[index].lastName}',
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(
                              '${userList[index].email}',
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  userList[index].avatar.toString()),
                            ))),
                  );
                });
          }
          if (state is UserErrorState) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text("Error"),
            );
          }

          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UserBloc**

```
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  final String pageNo;
  UserBloc(this._userRepository,this.pageNo) : super(UserLoadingState()) {
    on<LoadUserEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(UserLoadingState());
      try {
        final users = await _userRepository.getUsers(pageNo);
        emit(UserLoadedState(users));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(UserErrorState(e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**UserEvent**

```
@immutable
abstract class UserEvent extends Equatable {
  const UserEvent();
}

class LoadUserEvent extends UserEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

**UserState**

```
@immutable
abstract class UserState extends Equatable {}

//data loading state
class UserLoadingState extends UserState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class UserLoadedState extends UserState {
  final List<UserModel> users;
  UserLoadedState(this.users);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [users];
}
class UserErrorState extends UserState {
  final String error;
  UserErrorState(this.error);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}
```

**UserModel**

```
class UserModel {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  UserModel({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
class UserRepository {
  String userUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=';

  Future<List<UserModel>> getUsers(String pageNo) async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(userUrl+pageNo));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      return result.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check with the debugger if your BLoC jumps in this line:  emit(UserLoadedState(users));

Comment: yes it does emit, but it does not call the bloc builder state

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert `HomePage` to a `StatefulWidget`: This allows you to maintain the page number state properly. Also, it lets you interact with the bloc instance consistently.
2. Use a Single Instance of `UserBloc`: Instead of creating a new instance of `UserBloc` on every button click, use the same instance that is provided to your widget tree via `BlocProvider`.

how you can refactor your code:

Updated `HomePage`

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String pageNo = "1";
  late UserBloc userBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userBloc = UserBloc(UserRepository(), pageNo)..add(LoadUserEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => userBloc,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('The BloC App')),
        body: blocBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              pageNo = "2"; // Update the page number
            });
            userBloc.add(LoadUserEvent()); // Use the existing bloc instance
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget blocBody() {
    return BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        // Your existing BlocBuilder code
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is here it is creating new bloc instance with new `UserRepository`  repository. You can create singleton class if you like.

To use access the current bloc instance you can use `BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);`.

```dart
   final bloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
   bloc.add(LoadUserEvent());
```

> You can not access the bloc the same context you create it. You can use Builder or new widget for separate context.

Now while we fetch data, the old data is replaced by new data instead of extending the list. Therefor I am modifying the bloc like

```dart
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  final String pageNo; //I prefer using event for this.
  UserBloc(this._userRepository, this.pageNo) : super(UserLoadingState()) {
    on<LoadUserEvent>((event, emit) async {
      // emit(UserLoadingState()); //not needed, else we need to lift up the old user list
      debugPrint("pageNo $pageNo");
      try {
        final users = await _userRepository.getUsers(pageNo);
        List<UserModel> oldUser = []; //get the old user list
        if (state is UserLoadedState) {
          oldUser = (state as UserLoadedState).users;
          debugPrint("oldUser.length ${oldUser.length}");
        }
        emit(UserLoadedState([...oldUser, ...users]));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(UserErrorState(e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

Full snippet

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String pageNo = "1";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => UserBloc(UserRepository(), pageNo)
            ..add(LoadUserEvent()), //initially load the user
        ),
      ],
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          /// you cant directly access the bloc from here, so use builder or new widget
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('The BloC App')),
            body: blocBody(),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final bloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
                var pageNo = "2";
                bloc.add(LoadUserEvent());
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget blocBody() {
    return BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is UserLoadingState) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        if (state is UserLoadedState) {
          List<UserModel> userList = state.users;
          debugPrint("userList.length ${userList.length}");
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: userList.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 8),
                  child: Card(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        '${userList[index].firstName}  ${userList[index].lastName}',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        '${userList[index].email}',
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                          // backgroundImage:
                          //     NetworkImage(userList[index].avatar.toString()),
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        }
        if (state is UserErrorState) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Error"),
          );
        }

        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}

class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  final String pageNo;
  UserBloc(this._userRepository, this.pageNo) : super(UserLoadingState()) {
    on<LoadUserEvent>((event, emit) async {
      // emit(UserLoadingState()); //not needed, else we need to lift up the old user list
      debugPrint("pageNo $pageNo");
      try {
        final users = await _userRepository.getUsers(pageNo);
        List<UserModel> oldUser = []; //get the old user list
        if (state is UserLoadedState) {
          oldUser = (state as UserLoadedState).users;
          debugPrint("oldUser.length ${oldUser.length}");
        }
        emit(UserLoadedState([...oldUser, ...users]));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(UserErrorState(e.toString()));
      }
    });
  }
}

@immutable
abstract class UserEvent extends Equatable {
  const UserEvent();
}

class LoadUserEvent extends UserEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

@immutable
abstract class UserState extends Equatable {}

//data loading state
class UserLoadingState extends UserState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class UserLoadedState extends UserState {
  final List<UserModel> users;
  UserLoadedState(this.users);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [users];
}

class UserErrorState extends UserState {
  final String error;
  UserErrorState(this.error);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}

class UserModel { //also prefer extending Equatable
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  UserModel({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

}

class UserRepository {
  String userUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=';

  Future<List<UserModel>> getUsers(String pageNo) async {
//     Response response = await get(Uri.parse(userUrl+pageNo));
//
//     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
//       final List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
//       return result.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
//     } else {
//       throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
//     }

    return List.generate(
        3,
        (index) => UserModel(
            id: index,
            email: "email",
            firstName: "firstName",
            lastName: "lastName",
            avatar: "avatar"));
  }
}
```

Comment: emit(UserLoadedState([...oldUser, ...users])); - this line throws error on compile time

Comment: can you share the error message? you can copy & paste the `full snippet` section with flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used bloc much, but most state managements won't trigger listening event of variable changes when you modify a list that's why you should replace the existing list not just modify it.

what I mean is if you have `List A` don't `A.add()`
instead
new `newA.fromList(...A,[])`